# __stdcall with JNR

Tags: java, dll, native, jnr

I'm using **JNR** and trying to call to `__stdcall` function. I've already tried to load library with `stdcall()` convention:

```
mTemplateApi = LibraryLoader.create(FPTemplateAPI.class).stdcall().load("FPTemplateAPI");
```

And tried to annotate method with `@StdCall`.

```
public interface FPTemplateAP  
{
    @StdCall
    Pointer CreateTemplateImage(@In ByteBuffer aTemplate,
                                @Out IntByReference aWidth,
                                @Out IntByReference aHeight,
                                @In boolean aColor);

}
```

As result I get the following error when I try to call to method:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: The operation completed successfully.

at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.AsmRuntime.newUnsatisifiedLinkError(AsmRuntime.java:40)
```

Comment: I posted issue on JNR github by the way https://github.com/jnr/jnr-ffi/issues/65

Answer (score 0):

For now I created another dll that delegates to `__stdcall` dll, but uses `__cdecl`, and it perfectly works for me.